# Trouble with creating a login

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make sure our usernames include a number in it and our password is 012345678. Is this correct for that? I have a table with email, username and password in my HTML.

```
document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var user = document.querySelector(" input[name=username]");
  var pass = document.querySelector(" input[name=password]");

  if (user.value.includes(0) ||
    user.value.includes(1) ||
    user.value.includes(2) ||
    user.value.includes(3) ||
    user.value.includes(4) ||
    user.value.includes(5) ||
    user.value.includes(6) ||
    user.value.includes(7) ||
    user.value.includes(8) ||
    user.value.includes(9)) {
    // user is good
    //now.. check the password
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect");
  }

  if (pass == 012345678) {
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect");
  }

  var Hmmm = document.getElementsByClassName("h1")[1]; {
    document.querySelector("h1").innerText = "Good Job"
  }    
});
```

Comment: You probably want Code Review SE, down the hall and to the right. SO is a terrible way to debug small programs.

Comment: jdv great tip man keep killing it, ill see you on code review

Answer (score 0):

Not quite right, no.

Your "pass" and "user" variables will be holding strings. So you need to use string functions on them, and compare them to strings.

This means that you can't use "includes" as it is not a valid [string function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods_2). Instead, you would use

```
user.value.indexOf("0")>=0 // indexOf will return -1 if it can't find what you are looking for
```

That being said, there's a much better way to test if a string contains at least one digit, using [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
user.value.match(/[0-9]/)
```

Finally, as I said, you need to compare strings with strings. So for your password check:

```
pass.value === "012345678"
```

I used the strict equality operator (===) because in this case, you absolutely want the value to be this full string. When you use the normal equality operator (==) there might be some casting that happens sometimes and produces false positives.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

### I recommend using Regex

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('test').onclick = function() {
    // test username
    var uname = document.getElementById('username').value;
    // test password
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

    if (checkUsername(uname) && checkPassword(password)) {
      console.log('everything is good!');
    } else {
      console.log('something is wrong');
    }
  }
}

function checkUsername(uname) {
  // checks if the username contains a digit with regex
  if (/\d/.test(uname)) {
    console.log('Username contains digit');
    return true;
  } else {
    console.log('Username needs to have a digit in it.');
    return false;
  }
}

function checkPassword(password) {
  // checks the password to be equal to string constant
  if (password === '012345678') {
    console.log('good password');
    return true;
  } else {
    console.log('bad password');
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="username">Username: <input type="textbox" id="username" /></label>
<label for="password">Password: <input type="password" id="password" /></label>
<input type="button" id="test" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: @jsully77 np, anytime!